# Want GNOME theme back to default with no taskbar at the bottom

Tags: gnome, themes

My GNOME theme in Ubuntu has suddenly changed with some random changes such as the close button for applications have moved to right,  taskbar has appeared at the bottom, and mouse scrolling is in opposite direction and the top bar has also changed to white with time and date at the top right whereas it was in the top middle with dark theme and no taskbar at the bottom.

I want the previous setting back.

Here is the current look:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have somehow switched to GNOME Flashback (classic GNOME). Try this: first reboot your computer, then before entering your password click on the Ubuntu logo (or small gear symbol) and select GNOME session instead of GNOME Flashback.

Comment: If you're using Fedora, unfortunately we don't support that here. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema Are you sure they're using Fedora? Can it be deduced from the first screenshot? I believe they added the second screenshot just for a reference - they want their desktop to look like that. Most probably they got the second image from the internet.

Comment: @pomsky you may be correct.

Comment: @heynnema I have gdm v3.24.1 (Ubuntu GNOME 17.04). There **is** one gear next to the *Sign In* button which lets me choose between GNOME, GNOME Classic, and GNOME on Wayland. It looks something like [this](https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Install-GUI-in-Arch-Linux-14.jpg).

Comment: @pomsky well live and learn! You just taught this old dog a new trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I just noticed that they may be using Fedora... so this probably won't apply...

Open the `Tweak Tool`.

Adjust the three settings that I show to reset your theme...

[image]

Disable unnecessary extensions and set the prefs on the remaining...

[image]